# Book about a boy who leaves his village and goes to a large city. The cover shows two men having a discussion at the foot of Bruegel's Tower of Babel

Tags: identification-request

I'm looking for the name of a book I read three years ago (although it was published in the early 2000s maybe) about a boy who leaves his village and goes to a large city. The cover art is a corner of Bruegel's Tower of Babel artwork where men are discussing things at the foot of the tower. The part I'm referring too is the banner of [this webpage](http://www.artinsociety.com/lost-in-translation-bruegelrsquos-tower-of-babel.html).

Once the boy arrives at the city, I believe he befriends some beggars who fake illnesses. He then eventually becomes a painter's apprentice, before being forced to leave the city, and returns to his village with (this is a very specific part I remember) a handful of nutmegs. This is nutmegs as in the spice, whole nutmegs.

I also remember the name of the book being the name of the boy who is the main character. The author was almost certainly male. I believe the story ends with the boy growing old and regretting returning to the village with only nutmegs. It is not *Senlin Ascends*.

I have been searching for a year now. Is there anyone who has ever heard of any book like this and could point me to the title?